# Continuity of $F\left(x\right)=\int_{a}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt$ on an arbitrary interval $I$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, riemann-integration

I'm trying to solve the next problem: Let $f$ be Riemann integrable
on the interval $I$ and $a,x\in I$. Prove that $F\left(x\right)=\int_{a}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt$
is a continuous function on $I$.

So given $c\in I$ and $\varepsilon>0$
I want to find $\delta>0$ such that if $x\in\left(c-\delta,c+\delta\right)\cap I$
then 
$$
\mid F\left(x\right)-F\left(c\right)\mid=\mid\int_{a}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt-\int_{a}^{c}f\left(t\right)dt\mid=\mid\int_{c}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt\mid<\varepsilon
$$

The case when the function is bounded by a constant $M>0$ is easy
because I can take for example $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{M}$. But
I don't know if the function is bounded on $I$. Also if the interval
is compact then Riemann integrability of $f$ implies that the function
is bounded, but the interval is arbitrary and it could be open and
I have problems for choose the appropriate $\delta>0$. I'm thinking
that may be the problem could be wrong but I don't
know. Could you help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $f$ is bounded. That is part of the definition of Riemann-integrable function: if $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$ then $f|_{[a,b]}$ is bounded. And if you want to prove that $F$ is continuous at $x$, then you can assume without loss of generality that you are working on an interval $[a,b]$ with $b>x$. Unless $x$ the largest element of $I$. in which case you work on $[a,x]$.

Comment: Yes, In that case for compact the function is bounded. But may be it could be of the form (a,b) and may be the function is not bounded. For example 1/x on (0,1).

Comment: Let us then think about $(0,1)$. Assume, for instance, that $a=\frac12$ and that $x=\frac14$. Then consider the restrication of your function to, say, $\left[\frac18,\frac12\right]$. That restriction **is** bounded and therefore your proof works there. This proves that your function is continuous at $\frac14$.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the idea. I was thinking that if a funtion $f$ is continuous  on every compact subinterval $[a,b]$  with  $a,b \in I$ then it may be doesn´t implies that is continuous on the whole interval $I$. But that's true and is what you are using. Yes? May be I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what I am using.

Comment: Thanks for your help.